# Listar json con flutter android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

sucede que estoy iniciando con flutter y lo que quiero es listar un json que me devuelve un php, ya he logrado listar un array sencillo pero me gustaria listar desde un servicio web.

este es lo que tengo

```
class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {

  
  var tareas =[
    'desayuno',
    'almuerzo',
    'comida',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new Scaffold(

        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Volver'),
        ),

             body: Container(


        child :ListView.builder(
               itemCount: tareas.length,
               itemBuilder:(context, position){
                 return Tarea(tareas[position]);
    },
               ),
             ));

  }



}
```

Hasta ahí me lista el array sin problemas pero me gustaría que en vez del array sea

```
Future<List> obtenerlista() async {
    var url = "http://www.srvweb/tareas.php";
    var  responseList = await http.post(url, body: {
    });
  }
```

Esto me retorna el php

[{"tarea":"lavar platos","hora":null,"fecha":null,"persona":"pedrito"}]

Como puede implementarlo en vez del array ?

Comment: que te retorna esto ? http://www.srvweb/tareas.php ,   es post o get ?

Comment: retorna una lista codificada json segun un parametro,  responseList  obtendria la lista

Comment: podrías poner el json que retorna en tu pregunta, actualizala para poder ayudar en como puedes mostrar la información.

Comment: [{"tarea":"lavar platos","hora":null,"fecha":null,"persona":"pedrito"}]

Comment: ya la actualice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero tienes que convertir el widget a `StatefulWidget` o también podrías usar `FutureBuilder`.

Este es un ejemplo con `StatefulWidget` :

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class SecondRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondRouteState createState() => _SecondRouteState();
}

class _SecondRouteState extends State<SecondRoute> {
  List<String> tareas = [];

  Future<List<String>> obtenerlista() async {
    var url = "http://www.srvweb/tareas.php";
    var response = await http.get(url);
    final datos = jsonDecode(response.body) as List;
    setState(() {
      tareas = datos.map((e) => e['tarea'] as String ).toList();
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    obtenerlista();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Volver'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: tareas.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, position) {
              return Tarea(tareas[position]);
            },
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

OJO: solo estoy obteniendo el campo `tarea` del json que mandaste, también podrías hacer la conversión a objeto.

Te recomiendo este enlace https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Comment: Gracias aunque todavía no me funciona seguiré investigando con el link que proporcionaste

Comment: No se que sucede, no hay errores en el codigo y no me devuelve nada

Comment: puse un toast  de tareas para ver que mostraba y solo sale []

Comment: donde pruebas, simulador? dispositivo? donde pusiste el toast? please da más detalles, has probado el servicio ? te retorna datos si lo ejecutas en tu navegador?

Comment: Si claro el php funciona perfectamente porque lo integro con otras tecnologías me devuelve el json codificado que te mostré en cuanto a la emulación esta bien ya he echo loguin   en flutter y dodo salio bien, yo creeria que es algun impedimento al leer el json es decir la descodificación

Comment: pinta datos para ver q devuelve : final datos = jsonDecode(response.body) as List;  debajo de eso pon :  print(datos) y pon la respuesta aquí

Comment: exactamente mostro esto es el logcat :     [{tarea: lavar platos, hora: null, fecha: null, persona: pedrito}]

Comment: ahora debajo de esto   tareas = datos.map((e) => e['tarea']).toList();  pon print(tareas) y mira el resultado

Comment: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'

Comment: ok, revisa mi codigo actualizado